# scipy find_peaks minimal values for begin and end of peak

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using scipy's find_peaks to find peaks in my dataset.

Now I am using the arguments 'height' and 'distance' to play with the peaks that are detected.

Is there also a specific argument that tells that the signal should go below a threshold value, before the next peak can be detected?

An example is below, where the peak is unusually wide and three peaks are detected, but where I want to save this as only one peak, because the signal did not go below my threshold.

I could fix it by increasing width, but than I would miss other smaller peaks.

Currently used code:

```
scp_peaks, properties = find_peaks(
    plotdf['G2'].values, height = 1.1*bg_G2.values, width = 9)
```

[Example of data where three peaks are detected, but the signal did not go below the threshold, so I only want one peak.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbbh3.png)

Comment: I would try two appraoches: 1) An elegant selection of `distance`, `rel_height` and `prominence`. 2) Data smoothing and peak identification on the smoothed data.

Comment: The `find_peaks` documentation has some examples, explanations and pointers to other options and functions. Any of those might help you out.